# TestFlight: If I remove and re-add myself as a tester, will I lose access to App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm an admin on my team's account on App Store Connect. I'm added as a tester, but I can't access builds on TestFlight on my phone, so I want to remove and re-add myself so I get the invitation again. I'm worried that this will mess something up, that I won't be able to log in and push new build to TestFlight or something. Will anything like this happen? Or can I safely remove and re-add myself as a tester?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely remove and re-add yourself as a tester in TestFlight. It doesn't remove your account for App Store Connect.